# comparar un valor con una columna array bidimensional

Tags: java, array-bidimensional

estaba tratando de sacar un valor igual o superior a nueve en un array bidimensional, pero NO termino de dar con "la tecla", os dejo por donde voy a ver si me ayudáis:

```
     String [][] bi ={{" M01","8","5","7"},{" M02","3","8","9"},{" M03","9","7","6"},{" M04","10","4","9"}};



     System.out.println("\nLos elementos del Array son:");
     for (int fila=0; fila<bi.length; fila++){
         System.out.println();
         for(int columna=0; columna<bi.length; columna++){
             System.out.print(bi[fila][columna]+" ");
         }
     }


     int  [][] arrayNumero = new int[4][4]; /*creamos una array int donde almacenar la conversión*/

        for(int i=0;i<bi.length;i++)
        {
            for(int j=1;j<bi.length;j++) /*partimos desde x=1 para evitar la conversion de los strings M01, etc*/
            {


                arrayNumero[i][j]=Integer.parseInt(bi[i][j]);
            }
        }

        System.out.print("\n_______________________\n");

                    /*avanzamos por columnas igual que en case anterior*/
         int mayor=0;           /*damos valor 9 y crearemos la condición de mayor o igual a 9*/

         for(int i=0; i<arrayNumero.length; i++){   
             for(int j=0;j<arrayNumero.length; j++) {
                 if(arrayNumero[0][j]>=9) {
                     mayor=arrayNumero[0][j];
                 }
             }


            } System.out.print("Módulo 01, Nota: "+mayor);



     } //end class

} //end class
```

En este caso NO se cumple porque en el M01 ningún valor es igual o supoerior a nueve, por lo que en este caso megustaría imprimir otro mensaje, como "Asignatura Sin Sobresaliente".
Si cambiamos una nota del M01 por un nueve, por ejemplo, sí que funciona, pero si no, No.

Comment: Por qué no comparas si `mayor` sigue siendo `0` entonces imprima el mensaje "Sin sobresaliente" en caso contrario que imprima el mensaje que ahorita tienes `"Modulo 1, Nota: "+mayor`

Comment: pero si lo mento dentro del for me lo imprime cuatro veces, si lo saco no me reconoce la varible

Comment: El `if` va exactamente donde tienes tu mensaje de "Modulo 1, Nota: ", justo al terminar los 2 cilcos `for`

Comment: lo siento, no me entero.

Answer (score 0):

Podrías hacer de esta manera (solo modifico desde la linea del mayor)

```
       /*avanzamos por columnas igual que en case anterior*/
       /*damos valor 9 y crearemos la condición de mayor o igual a 9*/ 
       int mayor = 0;

       for(int i=0; i<arrayNumero.length; i++){
       mayor = 0;
            for(int j = 0; j < arrayNumero.length; j++) {
                 if(arrayNumero[i][j] >= 9 && arrayNumero[i][j] > mayor) {
                     mayor = arrayNumero[i][j];
                 }
            }

            if(mayor > 0) {
                System.out.print("Módulo" + bi[i][0] + " -  Nota: " + mayor);
            } else {
                System.out.print("Módulo" + bi[i][0] + " - Sin sobrasalientes"); 
            }
            System.out.print("\n_______________________\n");
      }
```

Haciendolo así tenes las siguientes ventajas:

1) Revisas todos los módulos y no solo uno.

2) No vas a quedarte con el último número mayor a 9 que encuentres (nunca se compara el número con el mayor actual, por ende, si en una fila primero tenes un 10 y después un 9, se iba a quedar con el 9).

3) Con el if ponés la mejor nota de cada módulo o aclarás si no hay sobresalientes.

Espero que te haya podido ayudar

Comment: Una cosa, si array es mayor que 9, por narices, debe mayor que mayor, no parece tener sentido el &&, no?. O estoy diciendo una tontenría?. Gracias

Answer (score 0):

Solo tienes que añadir una condición que regule el mensaje que imprime en función del valor de la variable mayor. Te pongo el código a continuación.

Lo más importante del código que te pongo es que te fijes en cómo recorrer la segunda dimensión del array con el bucle for y la propiedad length. Tal como lo estas poniendo tú la propiedad length refiere a la primera dimensión del array. Si no tuviesen el mismo número de elementos ambas dimensiones te daría error al compilar el programa `ArrayIndexOutOfBounds`. Para referirse a la segunda dimensión del array tienes que utilizar una estructura del siguiente tipo: `nombre_del_array[posición_de_la_primera_dimensión].length`. Puedes verlo en el código que pongo.

```
     String [][] bi ={{" M01","8","5","7"},{" M02","3","8","9"},{" M03","9","7","6"},{" M04","10","4","9"}};



 System.out.println("\nLos elementos del Array son:");
 for (int fila=0; fila<bi.length; fila++){
     System.out.println();
     for(int columna=0; columna<bi[fila].length; columna++){
         System.out.print(bi[fila][columna]+" ");
     }
 }


 int  [][] arrayNumero = new int[4][4]; /*creamos una array int donde almacenar la conversión*/

    for(int i=0;i<bi.length;i++)
    {
        for(int j=1;j<bi[i].length;j++) /*partimos desde x=1 para evitar la conversion de los strings M01, etc*/
        {


            arrayNumero[i][j]=Integer.parseInt(bi[i][j]);
        }
    }

    System.out.print("\n_______________________\n");

                /*avanzamos por columnas igual que en case anterior*/
     int mayor=0;           /*damos valor 9 y crearemos la condición de mayor o igual a 9*/

     for(int i=0; i<arrayNumero.length; i++){   
         for(int j=0;j<arrayNumero[i].length; j++) {
             if(arrayNumero[0][j]>=9) {
                 mayor=arrayNumero[0][j];
             } 
         }
        } 
     if(mayor==0)
         System.out.print("Asignatura sin sobresaliente");
     else
         System.out.print("Módulo 01, Nota: "+mayor);
```

Answer (score 0):

Siguiendo las indicaciones de Nahuel Giani y tras pensar un poco, lo he solventado con:

int sobre=0;

```
                for(int i=0; i<arrayNumero.length; i++){    
                     for(int j=0;j<arrayNumero.length; j++) {
                         if (arrayNumero[i][j]>sobre) {
                             sobre=arrayNumero[0][j];           /*asigamos el valor más alto de la columna ELEGIDA (CERO) DEL array a "sobre"*/
                         }
                     }
                  }
                 if (sobre>=9) {
                     System.out.print("Módulo 01, CON Nota Sobresaliente: "+sobre);                          
                 } else {
                        System.out.print("Módulo 01 Sin sobrasalientes: " +sobre); 
                    }
             }
```